# Storing sockets in vectors to then close, same socket keeps getting added

Tags: c++, sockets, vector

I am learning C++ and sockets and I've run into a problem, I've created a small sample app to simulate it. I create a listen socket and then I connect to the socket and I store the client socket in a vector of type `SOCKET *`.

After the 3rd client socket connection I then iterate over the vector and close it. The first 1 succeeds but the the final 2 fails with -1 error as if the socket has already been closed. Yet only 1 socket actually closes.

Below is the code

```
WindowsSocket socketManager(&bitsLibrary);
    socketManager.createSocket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, 500, 1024, "127.0.0.1");

    socketManager.bindAndStartListening();
    vector<SOCKET *> clientSocketList;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 3)
    {
        sockaddr_in client;
        SOCKET clientSock = socketManager.acceptClientAndReturnSocket(&client);

        cout << "Client Port: " << ntohs(client.sin_port) << endl;

        //Add the client socket to the vector
        clientSocketList.push_back(&clientSock);
        i++;

        string data = socketManager.receiveDataOnSocket(&clientSock);

        socketManager.sendToSocket(&clientSock, "Hello, here is a response");
    }

    int index = 1;
    for (std::vector<SOCKET *>::iterator it = clientSocketList.begin(); it != clientSocketList.end(); ++it)
    {
        cout << "Closing socket " << index << " of " << clientSocketList.size() << endl;
        try
        {
            SOCKET *socket = (SOCKET *)*it;
            socketManager.closeSocket(socket);
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            cout << "Failed to close client socket. Error: " << ex.what() << endl;
        }
        index++;
    }

    //socketManager.closeSocket(socketManager.returnSocket());
    //socketManager.closeSocket(&clientSock);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

The create socket function is as follows:

```
bool WindowsSocket::createSocket(int family, int socketType, int protocol, int port, int bufferLength, string ipAddress)
{
    stringstream logstream;
    //Call the base method to do the prep work e.g. create the buffer
    BaseSocket::createsocket(port, bufferLength);

    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0)
    {
        logstream << "WSAStartup failed with error: " << iResult;
        this->bitsLibrary->writeToLog(logstream.str(), "WindowsSocket", "createSocket");
        logstream.clear();
        logstream.str(string());
        return false;
    }
    this->serverSocket = socket(family, socketType, protocol);
    this->serv_addr.sin_family = family;
    if (ipAddress.empty())
    {
        this->serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    }
    else
    {
        this->serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ipAddress.c_str());
    }
    this->serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);

    return true;
}
```

The bindAndStartListening function is as follows:

```
bool WindowsSocket::bindAndStartListening(int backlog)
{
    stringstream logstream;

    //iResult = ::bind(this->serverSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
    iResult = ::bind(this->serverSocket, (SOCKADDR *)&this->serv_addr, sizeof(this->serv_addr));
    if (iResult != 0)
    {
        logstream << "Socket binding failed with error: " << iResult;
        this->bitsLibrary->writeToLog(logstream.str(), "WindowsSocket", "bindAndStartListening");
        logstream.clear();
        logstream.str(string());
        FreeAddrInfo(result);
        closesocket(this->serverSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return false;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);
    iResult = listen(this->serverSocket, backlog);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        throw SocketException(this->getErrorStringFromErrorCode(WSAGetLastError()).c_str());
        return false;
    }
    logstream << "Socket has binded and is now listening";
    this->bitsLibrary->writeToLog(logstream.str(), "WindowsSocket", "bindAndStartListening");
    return true;
}
```

The acceptClientAndReturnSocket function is as follows:

```
SOCKET WindowsSocket::acceptClientAndReturnSocket(sockaddr_in *clientAddr)
{
    SOCKET clientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    //sockaddr_in clientAddr;
    socklen_t sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    clientSocket = accept(this->serverSocket, (struct sockaddr*)clientAddr, &sin_size);
    return clientSocket;
}
```

When I debug what the ``clientSocketList` contains each item seems to contain the same value as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: Debug screenshot of clientSocketList]

I don't see why the same client socket is being added to the vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each iteration of the `while(i < 3)` loop creates a new `SOCKET`. You save it's address but then it's destroyed at the end of the iteration. What you are saving is the address of an object on the stack, and each iteration the latest `clientSock` is at the same address.

`clientSocketList` is an `std::vector<SOCKET*>` while you probably wanted to use an `std::vector<SOCKET>`.

Comment: Ah of course, every time I think I fully understand pointers something happens and I change my mind again

Comment: Pretty much all of your use of pointers in this code seems unnecessary. For example, why does `acceptClientAndReturnSocket` take a pointer when it could either take a reference or return a `std::pair`?

Comment: Hmm good point, I used a pointer so it doesn't create a copy when it passes the socket, I didn't know about references - still don't fully - when I wrote the the method originally, but yea will prob go back and see what I can change. Although one reason I think I found for pointers instead of references, is if its passed as a ref its not obvious that the pass value can be changed, where if its a pointer its obvious it could be modified, although maybe it should be a const pointer